# Возможно ли получить свойство transform не в матрице?

Tags: javascript, css

Пишу функцию для анимации CSS свойства `transform`.
Для этого мне нужно получить начальное значение свойства и конечно.
Конечно указывает пользователь при запуске функции.
Начальное пытался получить из getComputedStyle но он возвращает матричное значение (`matrix3d(0.751754, 0, 0.273616, 0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, -0.34202, 0, 0.939693, 0, 50, 0, 0, 1)`).
Возможно ли получить начальное значение в виде `translateX(-50px) sclae(.8) rotateY(-20deg)` ?
Или нужно работать с матрицей? Какие вообще есть варианты для реализации программной анимации для `transform` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно вычислять значения по формулам. Формул слишком много для того, чтобы добавить их в ответ, поэтому дам ссылку: https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/